# problemas al leer array ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, array

que estoy haciendo mal?

estoy haciendo una peticion **ajax** que me devuelve como **callback** este tipo de **array** o **objeto**

```
[{"nombre":"Kabul"},{"nombre":"Qandahar"},{"nombre":"Herat"},{"nombre":"Mazar-e-Sharif"},{"nombre":"Otra"}]
```

a la hora de yo leer este array lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera

```
$.ajax({

   type:"POST",
       url:url2,
       data:{code:code},
       datatype:"json",
       contenType: "application/json",
   }).done(function(response){

       var text=response;
       var obj=JSON.parse(text);

for (var propiedad in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propiedad)) {
    console.log("En la propiedad '" + propiedad + "' hay este valor: " + 
    obj[propiedad]);
  }
}
```

el `ouput` es el suiguiente...

```
En la propiedad '0' hay este valor: [object Object]
En la propiedad '1' hay este valor: [object Object]
En la propiedad '2' hay este valor: [object Object]
En la propiedad '3' hay este valor: [object Object]
En la propiedad '4' hay este valor: [object Object]
```

estoy esperando que me arroje...

```
En la propiedad '0' hay este valor: Kabul
En la propiedad '1' hay este valor: Qandahar
En la propiedad '2' hay este valor: Herat
etc...
```

el  archivo php donde viene este array es este

```
$data=array();

     while($row= $stmt->fetch()){ 

        $data[] = array('nombre'=>$CiudadNombre );
               } 

     echo json_encode($data);
```

que estoy haciendo mal no entiendo alguna mano amiga plis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un arreglo de objetos no un arreglo de strings, prueba intentando esto

```
$.ajax({

   type:"POST",
       url:url2,
       data:{code:code},
       datatype:"json",
       contenType: "application/json",
   }).done(function(response){

       var text=response;
       var obj=JSON.parse(text);


       obj.forEach( ciudad => console.log(ciudad) );



       //Suponiendo que el nombre de la ciudad este en una propiedad llamada nombre
       obj.forEach( ciudad => console.log(ciudad.nombre) );

}
```

Comment: genial si que funciono ! como hago para poder leeerlo en el dom? estoy intentando lo siguiente en un div  obj.foreEach(function(ciudad){ $("div").html(ciudad.nombre) }); pero no me funciona pero si lo muestra en la consolola justo como queria

Comment: Si lo que buscas es **crear** divs o algun elemento del DOM puedes usar este código, no lo pude poner aqui en los comentarios pero, el ejemplo esta en la liga que te pase.
https://www.ingenieroperales.com/javascript-es6-fetch-api-2/

Answer (score 1):

Estás devolviendo un arreglo de jsons, al iterar sobre el arreglode json, cada elemento es un json.

En `for in` de javascript itera sobre las `keys`, es decir, cada que usas el `for (var propiedad in obj) {...`, `propiedad` va a  valer el `key`, que al no estar implicito, toma el númerico, es decir `0,1,2,3 ... etc`

Entonces como `propiedad = 0`, al hacer `obj[propiedad]`, es decir el índice `0` de `propiedad`, el valor resultante es `{"nombre":"Kabul"}`. Esto quiere decir que efectivamente es un objeto.

Para acceder a ese data, simplemente tienes que acceder a esa propiedad así `obj[propiedad].name`

```
for (var propiedad in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propiedad)) {
    console.log("En la propiedad '" + propiedad + "' hay este valor: " + 
    obj[propiedad].name);
  }
}
```

En esta opción valdría la pena revisar si desde tu php es necesario devolverlo como un arreglo de json en lugar de un arreglo de solo los nombres, lo cual podrías hacer

$data=array();

```
 while($row= $stmt->fetch()){ 

     $data[] = $CiudadNombre;
 } 
 echo json_encode($data);
```

y entonces podrías mostar esa info con el `for` de javascript tal cual lo tienes ahorita.

Si lo que quieres es tener un arreglo de json e iterar sobre cada uno, tendrías que meter otro for dentro de tu for de json ahora iterando sobre el objeto json como tal